# Omniture/Adobe Analytics occasional doublefiring of click event

Tags: adobe-analytics

We're firing an event off of navigation bar clicks, and occasionally it fires two events. The two requests are exactly the same except for

- The request ID (incremeneted by 1)
- The second event has a few additional fields at the end after "link name": Page ID, Page ID type, Object ID, Object tag name

Anyone know why I might be seeing this? Like I said, it only happens every now and again - most of the times it will send a single event with each click, but every so often it sends these double events a few times in a row.... see below - - thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The second tracking call that you see is generated by the ClickMap functionality.  I assume you have trackInlineStats=true in your s_code configuration.  The Page ID, Page ID type, Object ID and Object Tag Name are all values used by click map only.

I assume your intended tracking (1st call) is bound to each navigation link using jQuery or native JS.

The second call is dynamically bound to the navigation links by the s_code (and is probably 2nd in order behind your desired call).

What I think is happening is that a user clicks on a nav link, the tracking you bound to the link fires and the page redirects *before* the clickMap auto generated tracking fires.

The reason you see the second tag sometimes is likely because the page navigation is taking longer than normal and this gives the page time to fire the clickMap tag.

To fix this you have the following options:

1. If you are not using the ClickMap reporting, deactivate ClickMap by setting s.trackInlineStats=false
2. If you do want use ClickMap functionality, you need to delay your page navigation until both tracking calls have completed.

**Note**

1. H code version 27 and app code have built in functionality to make this delay work correctly.  If you're not up to date with your H or App code versions then you really need to update.
2. I produced a cheat sheet to help with understanding the URL parameters, it may be some help to you: http://www.cheatography.com/dmpg-tom/cheat-sheets/adobe-analytics-omniture-sitecatalyst-parameters/

Let me know how you get on with this idea.

Comment: Wow - awesome, thanks for all of this. Yes s.trackInlineStats is set to "true" in the s_code. Does this mean it's actually overcounting events whenever the clickmap fire happens after the manually set event?*

Comment: Without doing some in-depth debugging on your site and analysis on your reports I can't really give you a definite answer.  My instinct says yes, you are likely double counting.
I don't want to sound sales-ey but if you need someone to look at this properly and provide accurate answers and advice why not try registering for a 1 hour workshop with my company: http://dmpg.co.uk/free-adobe-analytics-workshop/
This is completely free of charge and no obligation to purchase.  It will allow us to take a more in-depth view of your site, setup and reporting.